# htaccess, как блокировать пользователя по части IP

Tags: .htaccess

Я написал модуль,который отслеживает посетителей на сайте и я заметил, что ко мне постоянно, раз в секунду, заходит юзер.
IP адресс указывает на Китай, что китайцу делать на русскоязычном сайте не понятно, затем я заметил, что это не пользователь, python-requests/2.22.0 приходят ко мне. IP меняется раз в минут 20-30, но что я заметил, меняются последние цифры, тоесть было `120.132.11.115`, затем `120.132.8.110`

Возможно ли в htaccess файле забанить по началу IP, тоесть по `120.132`
Если нет, то подскажите как быть в данной ситуации.
Хостингу писал,сказали баньте по IP  или подключайте cloudflare или переезжать на VPS хостинг(этого я не хочу, меня все устраивает)

Comment: «Цыфры», Вы серьезно?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^120\.132\.
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Или так:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from 120.132.
Allow from all
```

P.S Вы не один такой, с этого диапазона ip ко мне также постоянно лезут китайцы.